# Rowchart select only a single bar in dc.js / crossfilter?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a dc.rowchart that has 5 different "categories". Initially, all are selected. When I click on one, then only that one is highlighted. When I click on a second one... both the first and second one I clicked are highlighted.

How can I make it/configure the rowchart such that only a single category is highlighted every time a bar is clicked?

```
dc.filter("category1");
dc.filter("category2");
```

Both of these in sequence appear to "append" filters than replace.

Comment: Have you solved your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Ethan's answer is almost there. It's likely unintentional, but dc.js doesn't appear to use the return value for `addFilterHandler`, so you'll have to modify the `filters` parameter for it to work, like so:

```js
myChart.addFilterHandler(function (filters, filter) {
    filters.length = 0; // empty the array
    filters.push(filter);
    return filters;
});
```

This works great as long as your chart doesn't use `cap` (e.g. a pie chart with limited slices), as this handler prevents the `others` group from working. I've yet to come up with a satisfactory solution for that case, unfortunately.

Comment: I missed this because it did not have the dc.js tag. Yes, in dc.js 2.0, these handlers are not pure functions as you would expect. In 2.1 they are, and either way will work as long as your return the new `filters`. I haven't looked at the "others cap problem" but I'll bet there is a workaround if anyone is interested.

Comment: This, unfortunately, doesn't quite work: it allows only one item (row) to be selected but if you click on the same item again, all the rows are selected. Somehow, rowchart selects all the rows if the user clicks on the same row twice. How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you'll want `addFilterHandler` - https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.baseMixin+addFilterHandler

You'd probably want to do the following, but it's untested.

```
myChart.addFilterHander(function (filters, filter) {
    return [filter];
});
```